# how to Create Polymorphism indate type c#

Tags: c#

I want to write function that coder write what date type he want to insert to program, then the function checked whether it possible to convert a certain input to this type. The problem is, that I don’t know how to let coder choose date type.

i tried type typeof valuetype etc.

```
public object checkvalu()//(type t)I added the empty brackets just for the code to run 
    {
        //t output; This is the original code.
        int output;//Not found in original code, I just added the code to run
        string input = null;
        bool b =int.TryParse(input, out output);
        while (b != true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("the valu is incorct. enter new valu");
            input = (Console.ReadLine());
            b = int.TryParse(input, out output);
        }
        output = Convert.ToInt32(input);
        return output;
    }
```

public object checkvalu(type t)
I do not know what to put in brackets.

Comment: Do you mean date format?  Or data type?  What will the user type in?

Comment: How many parameters in your Functions?? and what kind of data you want to passed as parameter?

Comment: Can you provide an examle input-output? You input some value(let it be param1) and you'd like to convert it to a type(let it be param2) ? Do I understand right?

Comment: Please post actual code. It's confusing when parts are commented out and parameters are replaced with variables. Using "date` when it sounds like you mean "data" is also confusing. Altogether it means that we have to think about what you're saying *and* what we think you mean, which makes reading it more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming few things since they are unclear:

- You mean **data type** and not **Date Type** since I saw `type t` in your code,
- Not clear where user should enter the type he wants, I will just write the function.

So here the thing:

```
public static object CheckValue(string type)
{
    // Get the type from string
    Type t = Type.GetType(type);

    // Used in the loop
    bool isConvertable = false;

    // Initialize object
    object convertInput = null;

    Console.Write("Enter a value: ");
    while (isConvertable == false)
    {
        try
        {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            convertInput = Convert.ChangeType(input, t);
            isConvertable = true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // If the conversion throw an exception, it means that it has an incorrect type
            Console.Write("The value is incorrect, enter new value: ");
        }
    }

    // Just for output purpose
    Console.WriteLine("Value has the correct type!");
    return convertInput;
}
```

When you call it like this:

```
CheckValue("System.Int32");
```

This will be the output:

```
Enter a value: this is a string
The value is incorrect, enter new value: 10
Value has the correct type!
```